# Exporting .glb loose material color

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I'm new in 3d modeling and Blender.
I made a simple design with 2 materials, one of them is a mix of an image and a color.
My problem is that when I export it, the mixed material is broken, I only see the image, but no the color.

This is the one I made.
[image]

This is what its exported (I imported it on other project and inspect it)
[image]

And this is how it is seen(the black is after export and inportit again)
[image]

Comment: If you want to export, you can't use whatever shader nodes you want, you need to make sure it follows a pattern the exporter understands. See the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#exported-materials) to see what you can export to glTF.

Comment: To add to @scurest's comment, read through: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures.